Vaadin-TestBench upgraded to ver 24 - TestBenchElements not identifying
Recently our Jenkins upgraded to Java 17, so we have upgraded our Java/ JDK to 17 and vaadin-testbench ver to 24.3.x
After these changes we refactored a few things since few of the deprecated. Earlier we had Java 1.8 and vaadin-testbench 15.0.2 and everything worked fine.Now Vaadin elements after upgrading Vaadin ver to 24.3.x ...the existing ElementQuery class/elements not identifying ..Any suggestions appreciated?
<groupId>com.vaadin</groupId><artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId><version>24.3.8</version>

sample ex:navigateToPaynow(payNowUrl);able to launch the application 
browsersignInPage = $(SignInPage.class).first(); ===> getting errorsignInPage.clickGuestCheckoutButton();

@Step( "Clicking Guest Checkout button" )
public void clickGuestCheckoutButton() 
{try {guestCheckOutButton().click();

protected ButtonElement guestCheckOutButton() 
{return $(ButtonElement.class).last();
}

class:@Element( "sign-in" )
public class SignInPage extends TestBenchElement {

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context cannot be null at com.vaadin.testbench.ElementQuery.executeSearch(ElementQuery.java:403)

enter image description here

Did you only update TestBench or also Vaadin to 24.3?

vaadin-testbench 24.3.8  because Jenkins was upgraded and we have to upgrade Java to 17 after that all the testbench elements not identifying..

But your application has a different Vaadin version?
